# How to make directive work with text area using AngularJS ?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have angularJS directive that is working good according to below code but here i have problem its not letting me to increase textarea rows i am not sure why its happening i spent hours but could not figure out the issue.. i would appreciate help here...

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control"
        ng-model="processDTO.processStatementText"
        id="processStatement" placeholder="Process statement" maxlength="4000"
        chars-ct-tooltip-focus="{{processDTO.processStatementText}}"
        required>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

directive.js

```
angular.module('App').directive('charsCtTooltipFocus', function () {  
  'use strict';     
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<input tooltip tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="focus">',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              attrs.$observe('charsCtTooltipFocus', function (value) {
              var modelValue = value;
              var maxlength = attrs.maxlength;
              modelValue = maxlength-modelValue.length+' characters left';
              attrs.$set('tooltip', modelValue);
              }); 
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What do you mean not letting you increase the rows? Where in your code are you trying to change it?

Comment: did you try something like element.attributes.rows = something

Comment: @SunilD. I want to set textarea width to 4 rows so with this directive i am not able to implement it.

Comment: Or did you try to bind a variable to the rows element?  `rows="{{rowCount}}"` Show the code that you've tried.

Comment: @SunilD. above is all the code i tried so far

Comment: Maybe I'm confused this seems blatantly simple. But I just re-read your comment. You are trying to set WIDTH to 4 ROWS. That doesn't work. The rows attribute sets/affects the height not the width of the text area. You want to set the `cols` attribute on the text area to affect the width.

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion i want set rows="4" that is not working and also i tried with custom css applied height for the textarea that is working but behaviour is completely different than what rows attribute does for textarea

Comment: Ok, you've got a weird situation here where the directive's template is a text input, but then you apply that directive on a text area. The directive uses the `replace` attribute to replace the HTML for the text area, so now instead of rendering a text area it renders the text input. That explains why the rows attribute on the text area has no effect. You don't need two inputs (text area and text input). Just use one...

Comment: You are absolutely right i changed the whole directive see my answer below.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have to change directive because it was set to replace true and supporting only input fields, So below directive i implemented to made it work on textarea and input both.

directive.js

```
angular.module('riskAssessmentApp').directive('characterCounter', function () {
      'use strict';
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngmodel) {
                var characterCount;
                element.after('<p class="character-count" style="display: none;"><span class="characters-left"></span> characters left</p>');
                element.focus(function(){
                    element.next().show();
                });
                element.focusout(function(){
                    element.next().hide();
                });
                scope.$watch(function(){
                    return ngmodel.$viewValue;
                }, function(newVal, oldVal){
                    if(newVal){
                        characterCount = parseInt(attrs.maxlength - newVal.length, 10);

                    } else{
                        characterCount = parseInt(attrs.maxlength, 10);
                    }
                    element.next().find('.characters-left').text(characterCount);

                })
            }
        };
    });
```